# Wp E-commerce filter product by price in store (Front side)

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I am not able to get any code snippet for filtering product by price low to high and high to low, I have one filter box with two options (1)low to high (2) high to low
Thanks in advance

Comment: could you be more specific, which is the technical problem here?

Comment: I have Installed plugin "WP e-Commerce" I want to add one filter box on front side, so that customer can sort product by price low to high and high to low

Comment: Sorry I forgot to Thanks for your response

Comment: I just suggested it would be great you be more specific in you question, your first comment is. Great you have found and shared the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer after too much searching just name your filter box with "product_order" and keep it's value "ASC" and "DESC" and form method to "GET"